# Hbase and 1- Many Relation

Tags: one-to-many, hbase

I have one question which can be best described by the following scenario.

Suppose I have three tables BaseCategory,Category and products. If i am thinking in terms of RDBMS then the relationship amoung these tables are

1- One BaseCategory has Many categories
2- One Category has Many Products.

Now i am thinking to convert it into HBase. can anybody help me how to map these relations into HBase?

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have each row represent a supercategory/category pair (encoded with a separator, e.g. MySuperCategory:MyCategory, and a column family named "products" with a column for each product in that category.

This would allow you to very quickly retrieve all of the items in a given supercategory/category pair, and with some de-duplication all of the items in a supercategory.